# Is there a function I can use for picking out a range of large numbers in java in an if statement

Tags: java

I am trying to create a human resource database and I want to select a range of numbers that should show a worker should retire when they reach the age of 60

```java
String Age = jtxtAge.getText();
if (Age.matches("^[0-59]*$")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Valid");
}
else {
    jtxtAge.setBackground(Color.red);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Due for retirement");
    return;
}
```

The .matches function only allows me to select the first index of a number, so an age of 26 would still show 'Due for retirement'.

Comment: you could parse the age to integer and check if it is >= 60, or are you bound to using regex?

Comment: Have you check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)?

Comment: You might want to use a `JSpinner` with a [`SpinnerNumberModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html). That way you can get the value directly as an `int` value and can even limits the way what the user can enter (only digits, must be positive, ...).

Comment: NB. Regular expressions are best used to match sentences from a regular language. To match numbers, use math (e.g. `<`, `==`, `>=`). On an unrelated note, convention in Java is to have (local) variables in camelCase, starting with a lowercase letter. This helps others to more quickly reason about your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the input age into integer using parseInt() method the check.

```java
String Age = jtxtAge.getText();
int age=Integer.parseInt(Age);
if(age>=0&&age<=59)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Valid");
} else {
    jtxtAge.setBackground(Color.red);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Due for retirement");
    return;
}
```